# Android/Crosswalk app installs using debug key, but "isn't compatible" once signed

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

I'm currently building an app using Cordova & Crosswalk, and building it using Phonegap Build.

When creating a debug app with no key and manually installing the apk, the app installs correctly and works as expected.

However, as soon as I sign the app for production, whenever I try to install the app I get the message:

> App not installed.
>
> This app isn't compatible with your phone.

I've looked into sdk versions, features, architectures etc and as far as I can see the phone I'm using is fully compatible. I don't understand what could be changing between the unsigned and signed apps to trigger this error.

What could be changing when I sign the app which suddenly makes the app incompatible, and causes the install to fail?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand the specifics about the signed/unsigned issue, the root cause of this was a change made in [Cordova Android 6.4.0](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/11/09/android-release.html) which broke compatibility with Crosswalk:

> Google also has changed the Gradle DSL used and currently support for the Crosswalk WebView is broken in this version of Cordova as a result. Unfortunately, since Crosswalk is no longer supported by the Crosswalk Project, we do not know whether this issue will be fixed.
>
> If you require support for Crosswalk, we recommend that you continue using cordova-android 6.3.0 at this time and avoid using or upgrading your project with Android Studio.

As mentioned in the article, forcing the build process to use 6.3.0 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue today. After tons of research, found a solution. Add the following line to your config.xml:

```
<preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="false"/>
```